# Breezejs registerEntityTypeCtor for base type

Tags: angularjs, odata, breeze

I'm trying to register custom constructor (add some properties) to entity. 
I've done it like that :

```
        var Entity = function () {
            this.prop = "test";
        };
        var store = manager.metadataStore;
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Entity", Entity);
```

And that works fine when `Entity` is the actual entity that I query. I've got a problem when `Entity` is a base type of object that I query for example when I have `Task` which derive from `Entity`. Property `prop` exists on Task but it's not initialized.

Is inheritance not supported ?

I'm using AngularJS and oData

**Edit:**
I've managed to do what I needed by using third param in registerEntityTypeCtor - init method. I initializ `prop` there. But shouldn't it work without init method as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the constructor is that it's taking a dependancy on things that don't exists in the definition until you've completed the query.

Since breeze creates properties as observables,
you can predefine the property you depend on as knockout observable:

```
this.prop = ko.observable("test");
```

Comment: I don't understand how observable helps with initialization of property in derived types ? and btw I'm using angular not knockout.